# "Variable length lookbehind not implemented" but it isn't variable length

Tags: regex, perl

I have a very crazy regex that I'm trying to diagnose. It is also very long, but I have cut it down to just the following script. Run using Strawberry Perl v5.26.2.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "M Y H A P P Y T E X T";
my $regex = '(?i)(?<!(Mon|Fri|Sun)day |August )abcd(?-i)';

if ($text =~ m/$regex/){
    print "true\n";
}
else {
    print "false\n";
}
```

This gives the error "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex."

I am hoping you can help with several issues:

1. I don't see why this error would occur, because all of the possible lookbehind values are 7 characters: "Monday ", "Friday ", "Sunday ", "August ".
2. I did not write this regex myself, and I am not sure how to interpret the syntax `(?i)` and `(?-i)`. When I get rid of the `(?i)` the error actually goes away. How will perl interpret this part of the regex? I would think the first two characters are evaluated to "optional literal parentheses" except that the parentheses isn't escaped and also in that case I would get a different syntax error because the closing parentheses would then not be matched.
3. This behavior starts somewhere between Perl 5.16.3_64 and 5.26.1_64, at least in Strawberry Perl. The former version is fine with the code, the latter is not. Why did it start?

Comment: Interestingly, it works on regex101.

Comment: The problem can be simplified even further: `/(?<!August )a/i` already says "Variable length lookbehind...", but remove one letter from `August` and it works fine. Remove the `/i` and it works fine. And if you want to laugh: `August` doesn't work, as show above. `Abcdst` doesn't work. But `Abcdet` works.

Comment: Maybe it's because `st` can be a ligature? Same with `fi` and `ff`.

Comment: perl 5.10 seems fine with any of these regexes, as well

Comment: I tested and this behavior starts somewhere between Perl 5.16.3_64 and 5.26.1_64, at least in Strawberry Perl. Updated my question to reflect that. The former version is fine with the code, the latter is not.

Comment: `pod/perl5220deltapod` in the Perl sources mention for "Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/%s/", that "The perldiag entry for this warning has had information about Unicode behavior added.". So I guess, that 5.22.0 is pretty close.

Comment: The plan is to fix these ligature lookbehind problems in 5.30

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I have reduced your problem to this:

```
my $text = 'M Y H A P P Y T E X T';
my $regex = '(?<!st)A';
print ($text =~ m/$regex/i ? "true\n" : "false\n");
```

Due to presence of `/i` (case insensitive) modifier and presence of certain character combinations such as `"ss"` or `"st"` that can be replaced by a [Typographic_ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=Typographic_ligature) causing it to be a variable length (`/August/i` matches for instance on both `AUGUST` (6 characters) and `auguﬆ` (5 characters, the last one being U+FB06)).

However if we remove `/i` (case insensitive) modifier then it works because typographic ligatures are not matched.

**Solution:** Use `aa` modifiers i.e.:

```
/(?<!st)A/iaa
```

Or in your regex:

```
my $text = 'M Y H A P P Y T E X T';
my $regex = '(?<!(Mon|Fri|Sun)day |August )abcd';
print ($text =~ m/$regex/iaa ? "true\n" : "false\n");
```

From [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> To forbid ASCII/non-ASCII matches (like "k" with "\N{KELVIN SIGN}"), specify the "a" twice, for example `/aai` or `/aia`. (The first occurrence of "a" restricts the `\d`, etc., and the second occurrence adds the "/i" restrictions.) But, note that code points outside the ASCII range will use Unicode rules for `/i` matching, so the modifier doesn't really restrict things to just ASCII; **it just forbids the intermixing of ASCII and non-ASCII**.

[See a closely related discussion here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1045325)

Comment: To contribute to this: It's also mentioned in [`perldiag`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Variable-length-lookbehind-not-implemented-in-regex-m/%s/): "There are non-obvious Unicode rules under `/i` that can match variably, but which you might not think could.". Another solution, apart from the `/aa` switch, might be reversing the string and do it with lookaheads, if you need Unicode support and variable length lookarounds.

Comment: Do you know why this behavior was not present in earlier versions of Perl? 5.16.3_64 does not throw an error but 5.26.1_64 does, at least in Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Yes this behavior is version dependent as mentioned in linked discussion as well. Unfortunately I don't have insight into exact version when this behavior started.

Comment: Replacing the `s` or `t` with `[s]` or `[t]` also seems to work around the problem.

Comment: Thanks and very good point @StephaneChazelas. Both `/(?<![s]t)A/i` or `/(?<!s[t])A/i` work without errors but using `/aa` is relatively easier than tweaking a bigger. regex

Comment: @Stephen – `ss` being matched by `ß` was present in Perl 5.16.3 but the other stylistic ligatures were added later, possibly around 5.22.  I've tried to map all digraphs with variable look-behind lengths, with as much versioning information as I could find, in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50765660/519360).

Answer (score 22):

That's because `st` can be a ligature. The same happens to `fi` and `ff`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use utf8;

my $fi = 'ﬁ';
print $fi =~ /fi/i;
```

So imagine something like `ﬁ|fi` where, indeed, the lengths of alternatives isn't the same.

Answer (score 2):

`st` could be represented in a 1-character [stylistic ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligatures) as `ﬆ` or `ﬅ`, so its length could be 2 or 1.

Quickly finding perl's full list of 2→1-character ligatures using a bash command:

```sh
$ perl -e 'print $^V'
v5.26.2
$ for lig in {a..z}{a..z}; do \
    perl -e 'print if /(?<!'$lig')x/i' 2>/dev/null || echo $lig; done

ff fi fl ss st
```

These respectively represent the `ﬀ`, `ﬁ`, `ﬂ`, `ß`, and `ﬆ`/`ﬅ` ligatures.  
<sup>(`ﬅ` represents `ſt`, using the obsolete [long s character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s); it matches `st` and it does *not* match `ft`.)</sup>

Perl also supports the remaining stylistic ligatures, `ﬃ` and `ﬄ` for `ffi` and `ffl`, though this isn't noteworthy in this context since lookbehinds already have issues with `ﬀ` and `ﬁ`/`ﬂ` separately.

Future releases of perl may include more stylistic ligatures, though all that remain are font-specific (e.g. [Linux Libertine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Libertine#Unicode_coverage) has stylistic ligatures for `ct` and [`ch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(digraph))) or debatably stylistic (such as the Dutch [`ĳ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_(digraph)#Encoding) for `ij` or the obsolete Spanish [`ꝇ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ll#Spanish) for `ll`).  It doesn't seem appropriate to have this treatment for ligatures that are not entirely interchangeable (nobody would accept `dœs` for `does`), though there are other scenarios, such as including `ß` thanks to its [uppercase form being `SS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Keyboards_and_encoding).

Perl 5.16.3 (and similarly old versions) only stumble on `ss` (for `ß`) and fail to expand the other ligatures in lookbehinds (they have fixed width and will not match). I didn't seek out the bugfix to itemize exactly which versions are affected.

Perl 5.14 introduced ligature support, so earlier versions don't have this problem.

### Workarounds

Workarounds for `/(?<!August)x/i` (only the first will properly avoid `Auguﬆ`):

- `/(?<!Augus[t])(?<!Augu(?=st).)x/i` (absolutely comprehensive)
- `/(?<!Augu(?aa:st))x/i` (just the `st` in the lookbehind is "ASCII-safe" ²)
- `/(?<!(?aa)August)x/i` (the whole the lookbehind is "ASCII-safe" ²)
- `/(?<!August)x/iaa` (the whole regex is "ASCII-safe" ²)
- `/(?<!Augus[t])x/i` (breaks ligature seeking ¹)
- `/(?<!Augus.)x/i` (slightly different, matches more)
- `/(?<!Augu(?-i:st))x/i` (case-sensitive `st` in lookbehind, won't match `AugusTx`)

These toy with removing the *case-insensitive modifier*¹ or adding the *ASCII-safe modifier*² in various places, often requiring the regex writer to specifically know of the variable-width ligature.

The first variation (which is the only comprehensive one) matches the variable widths with two lookbehinds: first for the six character version (no ligatures as noted in the first quote below) and second for any ligatures, employing a *forward* lookahead (which has zero width!) for `st` (including the ligatures) and then accounting for its single character width with a `.`

Two segments of the [`perlre` man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

#### ¹ Case-insensitive modifier `/i` & ligatures

> There are a number of Unicode characters that match a sequence of
>   multiple characters under `/i`.  For example, "LATIN SMALL LIGATURE
>   FI" should match the sequence `fi`.  Perl is not currently able to
>   do this when the multiple characters are in the pattern and are
>   split between groupings, or when one or more are quantified.  Thus
>
> ```php
> "\N{LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI}" =~ /fi/i;          # Matches [in perl 5.14+]
> "\N{LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI}" =~ /[fi][fi]/i;    # Doesn't match!
> "\N{LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI}" =~ /fi*/i;         # Doesn't match!
> "\N{LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI}" =~ /(f)(i)/i;      # Doesn't match!
> ```

#### ² ASCII-safe modifier `/aa` (perl 5.14+)

> To forbid ASCII/non-ASCII matches (like `k` with `\N{KELVIN SIGN}`),
>   specify the `a` twice, for example `/aai` or `/aia`.  (The first
>   occurrence of `a` restricts the `\d`, etc., and the second occurrence
>   adds the `/i` restrictions.)  But, note that code points outside the
>   ASCII range will use Unicode rules for `/i` matching, so the modifier
>   doesn't really restrict things to just ASCII; it just forbids the
>   intermixing of ASCII and non-ASCII.
>
> To summarize, this modifier provides protection for applications that
>   don't wish to be exposed to all of Unicode.  Specifying it twice gives
>   added protection.

Answer (score 0):

Put `(?i)` after lookbehind:

`(?<!(Mon|Fri|Sun)day |August )(?i)abcd(?-i)`

or

`(?<!(Mon|Fri|Sun)day |August )(?i:abcd)`

To me it seems to be a bug.