# How to use the literal string "STDIN" in negative lookbehind in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to use a negative lookbehind to filter out some matches of a few strings.  Curiously, it seems if I use the string "STDIN", under the hood the code is actually trying to use the handle .

Example:

```
perl -e 'use strict;  print "/some/file/path/STDIN.json" =~ m/(?<!STDIN\.)json$/i;'
```

Throws:

```
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!STDIN\.)json$/ at -e line 1.
```

But if I get rid of the leading 'S' of 'STDIN', the interpreter doesnt complain as expected.

```
perl -e 'use strict;  print "/some/file/path/STDIN.json" =~ m/(?<!TDIN\.)json$/i;'
```

The interpreter doesnt complain.

Is there some special way to escape "STDIN" that I need to do?  Or is there something simple I'm missing?

For reference, I'm using perl 5.22.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50356241/1030675

Comment: `m/(?<![S]TDIN\.)json$/i` is a workaround

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question!